# Countif text (leading 0) versus number unexpected count

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

OK, I used this line in vba to check if the value exists in a range using countifs:

`If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng1, Entry.entr1.Value, rng2, Entry.entr2.Value) = 0 Then`

where `rng1` and `rng2` are ranges in the sheet and `Entry.entr1.Value` and `Entry.entr2.Value` are both Entry values from a Userform.

I noticed that if the range contains for instance `1` and the userform entry is `01` this returns a (from my judgement) false positive.

This can be reproduced with regular worksheet formula in the sheet itself:

When using the following `Table1` for reference where Table1[A] is a number stored as text:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1b |

**option 1**
If I use `=COUNTIF(Table1[A],1,Table1[B],"a")` it returns 1. While the table holds the data stored as text, I can partially understand this returning 1.

**option 2**
If I use `=COUNTIF(Table1[A],"1",Table1[B],"a")` it returns 1, which is expected.

**option 3**
If I use `=COUNTIF(Table1[A],"01",Table1[B],"a")` it returns 1, while I would expect this to return 0 because of the leading 0.

While I don't understand why the 3rd option does not return 0.
I'm really searching a solution that does return 0 and one that might be adoptable in vba.

I hope anybody can help.

Comment: Use sumproduct: `=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[A]="01")*(Table1[B]="a"))`

Comment: And if you're using VBA, you'll need to `Evaluate` the sumproduct.

Comment: Thanks both.: `If Not ws.Evaluate("SumProduct(("" & rng1 & "" = """ & Entry.entr1.Value & """) * ("" & rng2 & "" = """ & Entry.entr2.Value & """))") = 0 Then` does give the expected results. You could post as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Does anybody still have an explanation for the behaviour of countifs on the leading `0`?